# vim wombat colorscheme not showing up correctly in xterm

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I put the wombat.vim in my ~/.vim/colors/ and i have :colorscheme wombat in my .vimrc and yet the colorscheme is not what wombat looks like.

The scheme looks like a cross between two schemes.

Not sure what is wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at source code of `wombat.vim` I realized that it sets values of `guifg` and `guibg`, and those are for a GUI vim. Not my case. So I download a version which set values `ctermfg` and `ctermbg` for non-GUI versions. You can get the file [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2465) and leave it in:

```
~/.vim/colors/wombat256.vim
```

Colorschemes work in a 256-color terminal. Check your `term` value

```
:set term?
```

In my case the value was `xterm`, so changed it to `xterm-256color` and worked.

```
:set term=xterm-256color
```

Comment: I have found that apart from the italics and some transparency (which I won't get in xterm anyway), I am getting everything else. Thanks. This looks really nice. Now I can get back to actual work.

Answer (score 1):

Try with another terminal emulator or, better yet, using `gvim`.

Most of the time discrepancies between the expected colours and the ones you actually get are due to the way your terminal handles them, in particular for colour schemes outside the standard 16 colours palette.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the colon at the beginning of the line in your .vimrc